# SQL - Need to run stored proc with ~100 different params, what's the best way to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Assuming I have a table with one field called ID that stores 100 different integer values. I can select all of these rows simply by doing `select id from example_table`

I then have a stored procedure that I need to execute for each of these id's (as the sole parameter) and then select specific columns from (the stored procedure returns more data then I need). Besides executing the stored procedure 100 separate times into a temporary table and then selecting data from this table - how else could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass table parameter to the procedure.
Check http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168
**Update**

```
CREATE TYPE LIST_OF_ID TABLE (ID INT);
go
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1(@ids LIST_OF_ID READONLY) 
....
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of this? How could I then select specific data against the procedure also

Comment: Surely there's a better way then this? I can see this causing a fit with the dba's and likely don't have permissions on the server to do so

Comment: @Michael: The closest alternative I can think about is to use XML type instead of table variable...

Comment: @Michael we use quite a bit of xml parsing in our DBs, but you do have to shred the xml and get it into a format you want so you can work with it.  the DBAs should not be complaining about building types (Been in oracle a long time)....I would prefer this over large amount of params.